Let $K/F$ a field extension and $E,L$ subfields of $K$ which contains $F$ Show that $E(L)=L(E)$
Let $K/F$ a field extension and $E,L$ subfields of $K$ which contains $F$
Show that $E(L)=L(E)$
I think its just by definition because $E(L)$ is defined to be the intersection of all subfields of $K$ containing both $E$ and $L$
and $L(E)$ is defined to be the intersection of all subfields of $K$ containing both $L$ and $E$
which is the same or I have To do something more?

Nothing to add, really. Weird problem.
